# recording a twiml response via Twilio

Tags: twilio

I've looked at the docs and haven't found anything that is capable of what I'm trying to do. Basically I have the phone call user do a input via a GATHER, and is prompted with a twiml SAY response. Is there a way to record ONLY the response? Most of the recording options record either the user only, or the entire phone call

Comment: Are you trying to record the TwiML <Say> response?

Comment: yes i am,is it possible?

Comment: You know, I'm not sure there is a way to record just the <Say> response. What's your reason for recording it?

Comment: it was for a assignment, I've concluded it is impossible. thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Gather response cannot be recorded. If you need to know what user had entered, just say entered digits in gather action.

[Gather Documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather)